# How do I convert a string field to a date field

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using crystal reports with Nextgen. In template editor for nextgen I created a date field, however crystal reports is bringing this in as a string for some reason. So the date is coming without any of the slashes between 20170101 for example. I've very new to crystal. Is there a way to convert a column that I'm bringing in from another table to a date field? Also please let me know where I need to click to do this. I'm guessing it's format editor?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your NextGen is not actually formatted as a date but regardless...

Here is one solution if the string is always coming in the format yyyymmdd
Create a formula

```
date(picture({yourdatefield},"xxxx/xx/xx"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So what do I click to implement this formula?

Comment: You will need to create a formula and use the above code. On the right under database fields formula you can right click to add a formula. Drop the new formula on the report and run it to make sure it is what you need.  Sorry but I don't have time to teach you how to use Crystal Reports  :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula:

```
DateValue({table.dateField})
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Suggest adding a description of what it does and how it answers the question.